# How to know DPI and if picture is in CMYK

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick

I need to check if some pictures (eps, tiff files) are in 300 DPI and if it is in CMYK format.

I'm using imagemagick but I don't find any information about it.

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Some images won't have a marked DPI, or will be labeled 72 DPI even though it's not correct. Why do you need to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're looking for "Resolution" and "Colorspace" fields output by ImageMagick's `identify` tool.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php

`identify -verbose sample.jpg`